# Tradução em página de medalhas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Na [página de medalhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), este texto não faz muito sentido:

> Além de ganhar reputação com suas perguntas e respostas, você recebe medalhas pela ajuda especial. As medalhas são exibidas em sua página de perfil, **flair** e em suas publicações.

O que é "flair"?

Além disso, as medalhas **Entusiasta** e **Fanático** ainda estão com o texto em inglês:

> Entusiasta: Visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days. (Days are counted in UTC.)
>   Fanático: Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days. (Days are counted in UTC.)

Sugestões:

> Entusiasta: Visitou o site todos os dias durante 30 dias consecutivos. (Dias são considerados pelo UTC.)
>   Fanático: Visitou o site todos os dias durante 100 dias consecutivos. (Dias são considerados pelo UTC.)

Comment: `+1` - deixo sugestão de "durante" x dias. Em vez de "por" x dias. Mas se soar mal rm br_PT ok por mim. Não faço ideia do que é "flair" (!)

Comment: Soa bem também. Vou alterar.

Comment: Não encontrei tradução satisfatória em português, ou mesmo uma boa definição em dicionários em inglês, mas [essa entrada no Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flair) parece corresponder bem à nossa [página de flair](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe/flair).

Comment: Relacionada : [Flair não merece uma tradução?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/862/3117)